# What is the correct format for blocking users at the postfix level on a zimbra server?

Tags: postfix, zimbra

I have a zimbra 8.7.11 community edition server running on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.

This particular mail server is getting attacked by @qq.com domain.  The messages are randomized so that the from address and the server IP address that the messages are coming from are randomized.

Every 3rd or 4th message, the sender is  and the IP address of the sending server also changes, so it's pointless to try and block the server's IP address.

I was trying to reject the messages at the postfix level using this file:

```
/opt/zimbra/conf/postfix_blacklist
```

format:

```
qq.com REJECT
@qq.com REJECT
*@qq.com REJECT
```

I ran `postmap /opt/zimbra/conf/postfix_blacklist` afterwards.

This does not seem to block or accept email addresses.  This file seems to look at the host that the mesages are coming from.

So I tried editing this file:

```
/opt/zibmra/conf/postfix_reject_sender
```

adding

```
qq.com REJECT
@qq.com REJECT
*@qq.com REJECT
```

Then `postmap /opt/zimbra/conf/postfix_reject_sender`

Several thousand messages are still getting through.

What is the best way to block an entire domain?

EDIT: Here is a pastebin link to the results of $ postconf.  There were more characters in the postfix configuration than are allowed here in this serverfault post.

https://pastebin.com/11EXXiCj

Comment: please show your postfix configuration

Comment: Added postconf results as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding the following to the zimbra configuration, which in turns updates postfix configuration.

```
zmprov ms 'yourmailservernamehere' +zimbraMtaSmtpdSenderRestrictions "check_sender_access lmdb:/opt/zimbra/conf/postfix_reject_sender"
```

Afterwards, the relevant postfix section looks like:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access lmdb:/opt/zimbra/conf/postfix_reject_sender, check_sender_access regexp:/opt/zimbra/common/conf/tag_as_originating.re, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_tls_clientcerts, check_sender_access regexp:/opt/zimbra/common/conf/tag_as_foreign.re
```

Since I have already created the /opt/zibmra/conf/postfix_reject_sender file, and postmapped it, the changes take effect after about a minute.

Then I started seeing these in /var/log/zimbra.log

```
Aug 14 16:44:14 zimbra postfix/smtpd[6200]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[58.52.137.34]: 554 5.7.1 <783029163@qq.com>: Sender address rejected: Access denied; from=<783029163@qq.com> to=<gooduser@ourdomain.com> proto=SMTP helo=<bluegate-group.com>
```

The last thing to note is that the format for /opt/zimbra/conf/postfix_reject_sender is as follows:

```
baduser@baddomain REJECT
qq.com REJECT
```

Having just "qq.com REJECT" in postfix_reject_sender blocked any address that came from @qq.com.